# Relationship needed for interface and class in a class diagramm, C++

Tags: c++, class, uml, class-diagram

Lets say I have a simple interface and a simple class, implementing that interface

```
class Inter_simple {
   public:
      virtual ~Inter_simple(){};
      void do_something(Simple_class* cl) = 0;
}

class My_class: public Inter_simple {
     public:
        void another_function(Simple_class* cl);
        void do_something(Simple_class* cl) override;
}
```

where both of them are using the class Point, which looks like:

```
class Simple_class{
   public:
      Simple_class();
      ~Simple_class();
   private:
       int some_value;
}
```

So in the class diagram, My_class is implementing the interface Inter_simple, and has an association to Simple_class (since it knows about that class).

But what about the interface? Do I also have to draw an association line between Inter_simple and Simple_class?

Comment: Typically you would only create associations for when you have a property of the other type. For usage in a parameter a dependency would suffice.

Comment: So you are saying to put an dependency connector between my Inter_simple and the Simple_class, but an association between My_class and Simple_class - or also an dependency there?

Comment: Do you have a property/attribute of type `Simple_Class` in either one?

Comment: The example I have written in my question should be complete, or what do you mean with attribute

Comment: It was a rhetorical question. You don't have one. So no need for any association.